# Pithier "as a reminder"

Tags: meaning, phrases, synonyms

### Introduction

The phrase "as a reminder" is sometimes used to introduce content. For example, one human user of a shared commode might say to another, "As a reminder, please leave the seat in the fully declined position." The phrase seems to mean something like, "although I suspect that you already know this, but am not certain, I will say..." However it also strikes me that "as a reminder" is an invitation for the listener to ignore the speaker precisely because the speaker is telling the listener something already known to the listener (as entailed by the word "reminder"). Perhaps the meaning is more like "Please call to the top of your mind."

### Typical Usage

I tend to hear the phrase "as a reminder" over loudspeakers in places such as airports or ground-based transit stations. For example, "As a reminder, please do not block the doorways."

### Question

What is a pithier phrase that conveys at least one of the meanings typicaly intended by "as a reminder?"

Comment: "POLITE NOTICE"? Please provide information on how you would like the phrase to be used, e.g. on a sign or in a verbal instruction, and formal or informal, and the intended audience (if it is a subtle reminder it's going to vary a lot depending on who is being subtly reminded).

Comment: @StuartF I've added a "Typical Usage" section per your request. One issue for me is that the meaning of the phrase is not entirely clear in the context I most often hear it.

Comment: Conversational attention-grabbing markers include 'Right!' and 'So!' More formally, 'Attention!' and 'Now hear this!' have been widely used. On notices, a bold header 'Important' was once common in the UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imperative "remember" is often used in this way, e.g. "Please remember to leave the seat in the fully upright position."

Comment: Similarly, "don't forget" and "please don't forget." I mention this to suggest that "remember" and "please remember" may be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

To say, "i need not remind you" is to imply you are about to hear something you should already know. To say "let me remind you" is to suggest you should pay more attention to it in the future. Both of these drip heavily with pith.